# Maven putting META-INF and WEB-INF contents into classes

Tags: java, spring, maven, build, pom.xml

my pom.xml contents for build -

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>                    
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

my directory structure is standard -

[image]

But this is what happening in target folder , META and WEB INF are again copied to classes -

[image]